VB6 to VB.NET conversion failing with error VBUP102 "Unexpected error preprocessing file frmCA" and no frmCA.Designer.vb file is generated
I am running VS2008 on Windows XP in order to make an initial conversion of a VB6 codebase to .NET 2.0. Later, it is intended to remove dependencies on legacy ActiveX controls and then migrate to a newer O/S and .NET but this cannot be done in a single pass because the legacy controls are only licensed and available in the XP environment.
You may remember that both VS2005 and VS2008 shipped with a "Visual Basic Upgrade Companion" tool, but that MSFT discontinued bundling that in VS from VS2010 onwards.
The problem is that in six out of many forms the conversion process partially fails. For these forms, no *.Designer.vb source file is produced and I am unable to identify the cause.
In each failing case, the log file contains the following information:
    <File
        OldPath = "\\WORK\S\frmCA.frm"
        NewPath = "\\WORK\S.NET\frmCA.vb"
        FileType = "Form"
        Upgraded = "True"
    >
        <Section Name = "Remove" >
            <Issue
                Type = "Compile"
                Number = "vbup102"
            >Unexpected error preprocessing file frmCA</Issue>
        </Section>
        <Section Name = "(Declarations)" >
            <Issue
                Type = "Compile"
                Number = "vbup104"
            >Unexpected error in file frmCA</Issue>
        </Section>
        <Section Name = "(Pretty Printing)" >
            <Issue
                Type = "Compile"
                Number = "vbup9002"
            />
            <Issue
                Type = "Compile"
                Number = "vbup9002"
            />
            <Issue
                Type = "Compile"
                Number = "vbup9002"
            />
        </Section>
    </File>


As you can see there is no indication of position in the .frm or .frx file where the problem arises. VB6 is fine with it and the application runs as expected when built in VB6.
I am assuming that the vbup104 and vbup9002 errors stem from the vbup102 error and that I really need to identify the cause of this.
Does anyone have any real-world-experience tips or tricks that I could use to home in on the cause of this failure?
I have tried altering the VB6 form in an attempt to remove UI elements which I thought could be causing the problem but this is not getting me anywhere... there are too many combinations of possible cause and I cannot think of a sensible way to simplify the problem. I am hoping that someone knows a way of turning on "diagnostic level logging" on the Upgrade utility in the hope of zeroing in on the position in the VB6 .frm file where the processing failed.

There have been significant changes and improvements in .NET and .NET Framework over the years. You may consider abandoning any conversion (or upgrade), and just rewrite the application in either .NET or .NET Framework.

I agree that that could be a possible path to a bright new future but there is a long tail of history and IP encapsulated within the existing codebase, which is still operational today. It would be great to replicate the functionality without embellishment or omission while building on a modern platform, hence the attempt to migrate the source. A shame to be held up by this single type of failure in fewer than 2% of the forms in the application.

If it is just 2% of the forms (6 total), it might be more efficient to just re-create those in VB.NET. That might end up being faster than trying to find a resolution to this issue, and it will give you experience designing forms "the .NET way vs VB6 way".

Those 6 or so embody an enormous amount of complexity. It was my intention to engage in a refactoring exercise after moving all the code over to .NET because (imho) the tooling is superior in the modern development environment. It would still be my preferred option if someone with experience of this particular issue has some insight they are willing to share, especially if there is a trick (documented or not) which could allow additional diagnostic information to be surfaced.

I would in consider migration to say .net 4, or 4.8 and winforms. And NOT introduction the extra moving parts of .net core.  In other words, 100% leave .net core out of this equation at this point in time (and I suspect you are doing this, but I just suggesting as such). So, migration to .net 4.0 (or 4.8) should be the goal here. Even after using the migration tools, those forms will need love and care - even forms that supposed converted often will need some extra work and care. So, import or converting such forms to .net saves you have to re-layout, but will not produce a 100% working form

@AndrewHall Can you extract one of the problem forms into a new VB6 project (make dummy methods as necessary in another file) and then try upgrading that? Then there will be fewer things to need to fiddle with to find the breaking problem, and it could be the same problem in the other five files.

Thanks @AlbertD.Kallal - that is indeed the direction of travel, but I think I explained previously that I need to make an "intermediate stop" along the way to transform away from dependency on legacy ActiveX controls. The next transformation would then be to progress from VS 2008/.NET2.0WinXP up to Win11/VS2022/.NET 4.8 while still remaining on the Windows Forms UI. It's been over 15 years since I last worked extensively on a VB6 to .NET migration and I do know from experience  that there is considerable work to do after the "raw" output from the conversion utility has been generated.

Thanks @AndrewMorton. This is really the only option I would have unless I find a magic bullet from one of the StackOverflow community who knows how to obtain more detailed diagnostics from the Upgrade utility... It takes impractically long to run the entire project through the conversion each time in order to iterate in the hope of identifying the offending construct(s). I'll probably start work on that soon (tomorrow) but keep hoping for a richer diagnostic output from the tool...

I'm not sure if you can simply create a brand new vb.net 4.8 framework project, and then import each form one by one (add->add existing item). As noted, this may well get you the form imported, and then you have to cut+paste in the vb6 code to the code behind for the form, and then refactor. Unfortunately, my computer currently does not have a copy of VB6 on it (and it is the first computer in a VERY long time that does not have VB6 installed). So, it's been a long time since I attempted such a migration. I would also try a cut+paste from a VB6 form in design mode and see if the paste works

Thanks @AlbertD.Kallal - the problem there is that I am limited by the non-availability of a slew of licensed ActiveX controls which are only licensed on the development platform: Windows XP + VS 6.0. The only migration toolset I have available on that platform is VS2008 + .NET{2.0,3.0,3.5}. I would not be able to install the latest Visual Studio on a Win XP host. Nor can I (yet) work on the project on (say) a Windows 11 box because I would lack the ActiveX controls. Doing all that conversion without any means of testing until everything is completed strikes me as risky Hence the halfway house

P.S. I like your cut/paste idea and I will try it out. After all, it was only the .Designer.vb file which did not generate. The code behind was created, though I cannot say that it is as correct or complete as it would have been given the designer code.

The ActiveX controls are a issue here. I used vb.net to create ActiveX controls for VB6, and more so MS-Access. And I still often create COM objects for VBA to use vb.net (or c#) code all the time. However, using ActiveX controls in vb.net? Gee, it been years.....and my last version of VS that had the "make a ActiveX control" add-in for VS was 2013........

Since its the designer code that is failing, that suggests something wrong with one of the controls. The designer VB file mainly contains control setup. Similar to the other comment I think you need to find the problem area by process of elimination . You might start with an almost empty VB6 form and gradually add to it. I would take a bisection approach and gradually add 1/2 the controls / code, etc. That will go faster than you might think.

BTW I think your approach of gradual update is right on; I still use the old conversion tool in VS2008 too when needed. I don't think there is anything wrong with using ActiveX controls from a .NET project.

Thanks @StayOnTarget. I've made some progress but at a cost of needing to perform a refactoring exercise when it's a little premature (I was hoping to do that after I had eliminated all the compiler errors.)
Anyways, things are in a bit of a muddle just now... I will report back to this thread when/if I identify a specific cause of the VBUP102 VBUP104 and VBUP9002 errors. It feels odd to have a problem which has apparently never been asked before on SO so if I manage to clarify the issue maybe it'll help the next dinosaur who happens to be wrestling with some old code in future...
